# Should I use expo router v3 in prod and a question about getting prisma types

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, expo, prisma

So, I'm building a mobile app with expo and I have a preatty short deadline (about 10 days) so I have to be as effective as possible. I'm doubting wheather should I create a separate express server and host it or should I use Expo api routes. Is expo api routes option production ready and how hard is it to host it. I'm also wondering, if I create separate express server and generate prisma inside it, can I acces prisma generated types in my expo mobile application for gettint type safety. Also, I've came across the option to create a backend folder, a expo folder and a separate "shared" folder for stuff like databases, in that scenario should I also there initialize node project, generate prisma there and refference it in other two folders. And how would I host it, would there be a way to host a "shared" and server folder on the same server or it must be separated?